# How to parallelize file reading and writing

Tags: multithreading, file

I have a program which reads data from 2 text files and then save the result to another file. Since there are many data to be read and written which cause a performance hit, I want to parallize the reading and writing operations.

My initial thought is, use 2 threads as an example, one thread read/write from the beginning, and another thread read/write from the middle of the file. Since my files are formatted as lines, not bytes(each line may have different bytes of data), seek by byte does not work for me. And the solution I could think of is use getline() to skip over the previous lines first, which might be not efficient.

Is there any good way to seek to a specified line in a file? or do you have any other ideas to parallize file reading and writing?

Environment: Win32, C++, NTFS, Single Hard Disk

Thanks.

-Dbger

Comment: what is your filesystem and what hardware do you use?  if you only have one controller/disk, it may not be efficient to do parallel I/O

Comment: so is that means parallize disk I/O will always cause a performance degradation if only read/write on the same disk?

Comment: Dbger: If using a hard disk, yes.

Comment: if you are processing files, you may want to consider overlapping I/O and computation. If you really want to try parallel, you can split your files into segments (logically), seek to that segment, find beginning of line in the segment, and read until next segment.

Comment: @unknown I didn't know much about "split files into segments", but if disk I/O prefers sequential access, would the segmentation appraoch work?

Comment: no, but this is how you might make it parallel, just in case you want to play around with it. i do not mean literal segmentation, i meant read/traverse file in segments,

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/826163/does-having-multiple-partitions-on-one-disk-parallelize-writing-to-disk/826167#comment1140243_826167

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Generally speaking, you do NOT want to parallelize disk I/O. Hard disks do not like random I/O because they have to continuously seek around to get to the data. Assuming you're not using RAID, and you're using hard drives as opposed to some solid state memory, you will see a severe performance degradation if you parallelize I/O(even when using technologies like those, you can still see some performance degradation when doing lots of random I/O).

To answer your second question, there really isn't a good way to seek to a certain line in a file; you can only explicitly seek to a byte offset using the `read` function(see [this page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/read.html) for more details on how to use it.

Comment: So in file reading/writing, disk seek cost most of the time, which is the case in multi-threading environment, is that right?

Comment: Yes, disk seek time will generally be the bottleneck is a multithreaded I/O environment. You should try to serialize your I/O where possible.

Comment: Thanks Mike, just to confirm, is this only apply when read a single file, or also apply when read multiple files (thread 1 read file1 ,thread2 read file2)

Comment: What I said applies to ANY disk I/O on a single disk, regardless of whether there are separate files. Of course, caching by the OS or disk will have some effect on actual results.

Comment: But there are file systems that allow you to distribute files across different disk/disk sections to linearly scale your I/O.

Comment: This answer might need an update for 2022? We have SSD and NVMe drives now - concerns about a moving head no longer apply. Does the conventional wisdom on this topic still apply?

Comment: Here's an article with benchmarks published in 2020. According to this research, both SSD and modern HDD drives appear to benefit from parallelization. https://pkolaczk.github.io/disk-parallelism/

Answer (score 3):

Queuing multiple reads and writes won't help when you're running against one disk. If your app also performed a lot of work in CPU then you could do your reads and writes asynchronously and let the CPU work while the disk I/O occurs in the background. Alternatively, get a second physical hard drive: read from one, write to the other. For modestly sized data sets that's often effective and quite a bit cheaper than writing code.

Comment: Use a backgroud thread to write the output data gradually when CPU is busy with computing, it is a good idea. But as to read, there are not much work can be done as the data is not ready.

Comment: Dbger, it depends on the nature of your data. If you're able to queue a second asynchronous fetch to be satisfied while processing the first fetch's data you're in business. Again, it's most effective if the disk isn't busy with other I/O, so possibly not applicable to your immediate situation.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer to your question but rather a re-design (which we all hate but can't help doing). As already mentioned, trying to speed up I/O on a hard disk with multiple threads probably won't help.

However, it might be possible to use another approach depending on data sensitivity, throughput needs, data size, etc. It would not be difficult to create a structure in memory that maintains a picture of the data and allows easy/fast updates of the lines of text anywhere in the data.  You could then use a dedicated thread that simply monitors that structure and whose job it is to write the data to disk. Writing data sequentially to disk can be extremely fast; it can be much faster than seeking randomly to different sections and writing it in pieces.

Comment: When I write about 2M data into a text file, sequentially, it costs about 1 second on my machine, which is too slow for me. As to read, in order to form a memory structure of the file, I need to read the data in first, which is also too slow to meet my requirement. However, I would investigate the topics on overlap I/O and Memorymap file to see if that helps.

Comment: 1 second to write 2MB? That seems amazingly slow.  I just ran a test that writes 10M to a file in about 100ms, and my PC is no real speed machine (3.2GHz and I *think* 7200rpm drive).  What APIs are you using to open and write to the file with?

Comment: I am using std::ofstream to save lots of separated data in a loop. like "for(...){streamOut << x; streamOut<<y}", and I also have a 7200rpm drive with a dual core 2.16GHz CPU

Comment: That is interesting. If I get time, I may have to test that on my PC out of curiosity. I was simply using the Win32 APIs (CreateFile, WriteFile). But in reality, I would expect the streamio to go through those APIs on Win32. Or if not, it would still be through some kind of buffered I/O. The average latency of a 7200 rpm disk should be under 5ms.  That should allow for a lot of buffered writes. I suppose if the disk were completely fragmented into 4096 chunks, it would come out to 1 second/MB.

Comment: MarkW, it turns out that most of the time is spending on string formating when calling "streamOut << x << " " << y << " " << z <<endl". I then  changed the code to format all those data into a string first, and then write out to the file all in once, it costs about 24ms to write 2M data. Then by parallelizing the string formating there is a noticable performance gain. Thanks so much.

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad you got it sped up.  Those numbers make a lot more sense.  Thanks for reporting back on it.  I was curious but never had time to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal IO performance depends on a lot of factors.

- few large or many small files
- random vs. sequential access
- do writes need to be `fsync()`'d or is having data sitting in the write cache fine?
- is a single application thread sufficient for the processing logic to keep up with peak IO bandwidth?

The simplest scenario is large, sequential reads on a few files, the task being IO-bound and writes being asynchronous.
In that scenario one can keep both HDDs and SSDs saturated with a single thread issueing a few large operations and perhaps some explicit readaheads.

Things get more complicated when part of the application is CPU-bound or many small files are involved.

On SSDs this often is easily solved by throwing more parallelism at the problem because they have multiple hardware IO queues and suffer practically no penalty for doing parallel IO.

On HDDs the tradeoff is more complicated. While parallelizing read/writes and  other filesystem operations such as traversing directories and opening/closing files can prevent the IO request queue from emptying (queue depth = 0) this penalizes sequential throughput due to disk seeks.
So while as long as one can make large requests the QD equal 1. If one has to make many small requests then a higher QD can be beneficial. Additionally one can optimize IO patterns by looking up the physical disk offset of directories and then process files in physical order. This minimizes seek times better than what the IO scheduler can do when faced with reads from files scattered randomly throughout the disk.