# Multiple Threads to load xml files into memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, file

I have a set of XML files that I want to load into memory in order to process.

I am loading the files into a Collection and it seems that it is a lot faster if I load the files in a single thread rather than using the thread pool.

I would have thought this would have been the other way around.

Why is it the case that use multiple threads to load files into memory is significantly slower than if I just iterate through the file list and load each file one after another on a single thread?

This is with C# .net 3.5

The code:

```
ICollection<XmlDocument> xmlFilesToProcess = new Collection<XmlDocument>();

foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileList)
{
     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        (o) =>
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load((string)o);
            lock (xmlFilesToProcess)
            {
                xmlFilesToProcess.Add(doc);
                counter++;
            }
        }, fileInfo.FullName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code, I would guess it probably has to do with the fact that reading from disk is the slow part of the operation. Since the disk can really only read one file at a time the disk becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: I updated with the code, I guess then it makes no real sense to use threading in this case since I can only ever read one file from the disk at a time?

Comment: I would say it's a possibility. You could test by preloading all of the files into memory and then loading them single threaded vs the thread pool. That would take reading from the disk out of the equation. Of course, it could be other things. As the other answers have stated, if you only have 1 processor multithreading won't really help.

Comment: Could make sense if your consider to parallelize parsing, but of course this is mitigated that parallel reading can be hard on your IO system. The gain could be insignificant. @rsbarro, could use 1 IO thread that queue the buffers,and parallel parsers.

Comment: @rsbarro, I tried this, and the threadpool takes almost double the time. I have an i5 with 4 cores. I am loading 11,534 files and most are around 10kb each.

Comment: @dvhh In my comment I was trying to come up with a way to just determine if the disk was the bottleneck, but yes, I think that would be a good approach, using the single IO thread.

Comment: @Tom Jones: What if you remove the lock statement (just to monitor the execution times)?

Comment: @rsbarro, removing that makes no significant difference. I guess it is faster to read the files sequentially from the disk since with reading the files in multiple threads will increase the number of disk seeks which I guess significantly reduces disk performance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993699/how-to-parallelize-file-reading-and-writing

Comment: @Tom Jones If you tried preloading everything from disk and then parsing, and the threadpool was slower in that case, I would draw the conclusion that the thread overhead is more expensive than the XML parsing operation (as was suggested in other answers).

Comment: Yes, disk is definitely a bottleneck. I don't know if it is relevant to your case but if possible, try to avoid hitting the disk. For instance, if you are getting those xml data from the network or some sort, you might want to keep them in the memory and process them sequentially and save them separately.

Comment: @rsbarro you mention preloading the files into memory? Is that different to what I am currently doing here?

Comment: @Tom Jones From what I see there are two things that could cause the multithreaded approach to be slower than the single threaded approach. It's either disk I/O or threading overhead. To rule out disk IO, load all of the xml into a List as strings and then parse them single threaded vs. threadpool. If threadpool is still slower, then threading overhead is more expensive than the xml parsing. If threadpool is faster, then disk I/O was the problem. If disk I/O is the problem, then you could try @dvhh's suggestion of creating a single thread to do disk I/O and use ThreadPool to parse in parallel.

Comment: ok that make sense. I think I am going with @dvhh's approach and see how that works.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the code, its hard to tell.  If the size and/or number of XML is small and you only have one CPU then it could be simply that the context switching between threads is taking more time than is required to simply read the files.

**EDIT**

Now that I see the code you are creating way too many threads.  I suggest you use the Parallel.For of the TPL.  This is available for .Net 3.5

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx for more info on TPL.

Comment: the xml files are relatively small (between 10k - 500k) but there are a large number of them (>10,000)

Comment: You are creating way too many threads.  More time is spent creating a thread/context switching than doing the actual XML processing.

Comment: Does Parallel.For not use the ThreadPool internally? My understanding is that ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem doesn't actually create another thread, it just creates an item that will be processed by the ThreadPool. The runtime determines how many threads are available in the ThreadPool.

Comment: Actually, it looks like TPL does use ThreadPool internally, so I don't think Parallel.For will be any different performance wise than QueueUserWorkItem. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/f39e5c60-6d33-44b5-a430-8b4f5bf653da

Comment: Interesting. I was using the ThreadPool because I thought it didn't create a large amount of threads? Either way, the bottleneck is down to the reading of files in parallel from a single disk. At this point I was simply just trying to load the files into memory as fast as possible and due to my lack of knowledge re: disk I/O I mistakenly thought that multithreading would be quicker. For some reason I always thought TPL was only a .net4 thing, so I will be definitely looking into that for other threading I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to make a decision on multi-threading vs single-threading you need to benchmark, ideally on a machine that is going to run your application.

Multi-threaded code can be slower, because of extra-overhead on thread synchronization. Even if you use ThreadPool, there will be initial overhead of thread creation.

It is difficult to suggest what is better single or multi threading without knowing the details of the problem to solve.

Also, it is difficult to tell why one code is slower than another without seeing the code.