# How to split a file read across multiple cores in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a relatively large file (~10 GB) on my local machine that I would like to parse: for each line that has the string `"bobby"` present in it, I would like to store the whole line on an array. Here's my initial attempt:

```
function runner()
    io = open("large_10gb_file.txt", "r")
    data = []
    for line in eachline(io)
        if occursin("bobby", line)
            push!(data, line)
        end
    end
    close(io)
    return data
end
```

This works just fine. However, I see that when I call `runner()` it uses one CPU core (at a 100% utilization); I have 5 more CPU cores available to utilize on my laptop - how can I modify my code to be able to do this? In fact, does it even make sense to do this, as the file might be IO bound on my NVMe SSD instead of CPU bound?

This is my initial parallelization attempt:

```
function runner()
    io = open("large_10gb_file.txt", "r")
    data = []
    @distributed for line in eachline(io)
        if occursin("bobby", line)
            push!(data, line)
        end
    end
    close(io)
    return data
end
```

The above, however, returns an empty (0-element) array. So I added an `@sync` to synchronize the threads and guarantee return order:

```
function runner()
    io = open("large_10gb_file.txt", "r")
    data = []
    @sync @distributed for line in eachline(io)
        if occursin("bobby", line)
            push!(data, line)
        end
    end
    close(io)
    return data
end
```

This, however, returns an error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching length(::Base.EachLine{IOStream})
Closest candidates are:
  length(::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:571
  length(::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:728
  length(::Core.MethodTable) at reflection.jl:802
  ...
(::getfield(Distributed, Symbol("##169#171")){getfield(Main, Symbol("##9#10")){Array{Any,1}},Base.EachLine{IOStream}})() at ./task.jl:244
Stacktrace:
 [1] sync_end(::Array{Any,1}) at ./task.jl:226
 [2] macro expansion at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Distributed/src/macros.jl:337 [inlined]
 [3] macro expansion at ./task.jl:244 [inlined]
 [4] runner() at ./REPL[73]:4
 [5] top-level scope at none:0
```

I'm not uber-familiar with Julia (just started learning the syntax yesterday) but it seems like the `eachline` call doesn't have a method matching `length`, and so the `@distributed for` isn't able to accurately split up the work between the different workers.

Note: I did do `addprocs(4)` before I ran the `@distributed for`, after which `procs()` started returning `5`.

Comment: If you are using a laptop computer then you won't get speedup by multithreading IO bound operations. You might look for a more efficient data storage type than .txt instead.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question - I'm not necessarily looking to speed up this operation, but just how to actually solve the underlying computer science problem to better my understanding of this topic. @mmagnuski

Comment: That depends on what the underlying computer science problem is: if it is multithreaded file readout from a single drive, then it's better to find another problem to tackle. For more info why parallelizing file reading is not a good idea see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993699/how-to-parallelize-file-reading-and-writing

Comment: An interesting answer in the example you posted. However, the answer is from 2010, and is referring to hard disk reads. On hard disks I understand why you wouldn't want to do random reads given the physical nature of drives. In 2018, however, I have M.2 NVMe SSDs, with 4x lanes straight into my CPU. No moving parts. In the worst case, random reads are almost ~8x faster than the theoretical max of HDDs. If I'm not IO-bound, I can imagine how splitting this file into 6 pieces, having each core take a 1.67GB chunk of my original file, and then doing `eachline()` on each chunk would speed it up.

Comment: The action taken depends on where is the problem. If in your case `occursin()` is expensive than you should use multithreading with locking when the data object is appended. If IO is expensive you basically need to split the file (e.g. across many physical SSD drives). In some scenario (plenty of CPU, slow disks) it might make sense to split into many compressed files than decompress on-the-fly the streams.  `@distributed` is probably no good way to go because it requires lots data transfer between processes (slow!) . Give more details and I give you feedback what you should use.

Comment: "I did do addprocs(4) before I ran the @distributed for, after which procs() started returning 5" - you got one master + 4 slave workers - try ` workers()` to check!

Comment: using `@sync` makes only sense when its paired with `@async`. The body of @distributed loop will run independently across many processes and usually you need to have an aggregator function to collect back the results, e.g: `@distributed (+) for i in 1:1000; i; end`