# writing to file in parallel

Tags: python, dataframe, parallel-processing, joblib

I'm currently running my code in an iterative manner where I iterate through a dataframe and write the output to a file line by line

```
with open(subtract_output_file, "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in df.iterrows():
        a = row[1][0]
        b = row[1][1]
        writer.writerow(a-b)
```

I want to use parallel processing as thee above mentioned method is really slow for my program. I'm using `joblib`

```
res = Parallel(n_parallel, backend="multiprocessing", verbose=10, pre_dispatch="all")(
        delayed(function)(query) for row in enumerate(df))
```

I'm not sure how to write the output for this to a file simultaneously. Is there a way to atleast write it say in a batch of 100?

Comment: You would either (a) write to multiple (temporary) files and combine them at the end, or (b) just collect the data in memory and write it out when all the jobs are complete.

Comment: It seems like you're writing a pandas data frame to disk. Why use iterrows, and not the built it pandas function to_csv which is *MUCH* faster?

Comment: @Roy2012 Iterrows is for iterating through the data not for writing it.

Comment: @JohnConstantine - I get that. You're using iterrows (not recommended) and then the Python CSV dict-writer, which is even less recommended if what you're looking for is performance. Why not just panda's to_csv?

Comment: More generally, parallel writing to a single file may makes sense when different processes are dealing with different records whose size is known in advance  - like in the case of a database. In your case, you can either write multiple chunks and just merge them at the end, or - as proposed above - don't use iter-rows and dictwriter in the first place. 
(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993699/how-to-parallelize-file-reading-and-writing)

Comment: I'm processing the dataframe line by line adn then writing the output. @Roy2012

Comment: Why do you process it row-by-row? An alternative solution here would be to (1) do some pandas magic to create a full / new datagram, and then (2) write it using to_csv.

Comment: Each row as a query which has to make an api call to get some info related to itself, then I write that data into csv. @Roy2012

Comment: got it. Do you know what's taking the majority of the time? Is it the API call or the actual write to disk? if the API calls are REST / SOAP / IPC, they probably take the vast majority of the time, and then it does make sense to parallelize them. But again - it's a different problem than parallelizing the write to disk.

Comment: @JohnConstantine Did you ever find a way?!